# How can I write a python code where it extracts full names from a list of names

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write a python code where it extracts full names from a list of names. For example:

```
names = ['John', 'Jane Doe', 'Mark', 'Ray Charles', 'Meg'].
```

Expected result:

```
names = ['Jane Doe', 'Ray Charles']
```

Comment: Something like `[name for name in names if ' ' in name]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
storeFullNames = []
storeFullNames.append('Jane Doe')
storeFullNames.append('Ray Charles')
print(storeFullNames)
```

Second way:

```
storeListNames = []
for name in names:
  if len(name.split(' ')) > 1:
     storeListNames.append(name)
print(storeListNames)
```

both ways return a list with full names only...

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you want all the names that have more than 1 word in them.

If so, you can check this by: `len(name.split(' ')) > 1`

and the final code will be:

```
output_list = [name for name in names if len(name.split(' ')) > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep two lists: One for all names, and one for full names where the first and last names are separated by one space. Iterate through the names, and copy all names with a space to the full names list.

```
all_names = [ “John”, “Jane Doe”, “Mark”, “Ray Charles”, “Meg” ]
full_names = []

for name in all_names:
  if “ “ in name:
    full_names.append(name)
```

Comment: this is not 100% correct..., needs to be `full_names = []`, and a few other issues..there's no empty string `" " in all_names:`

Comment: @FishingCode Thank you, I do not use Python seriously and am minorly rusty. The empty string is meant to be a space.